# What memory should I look at (WorkingSet, VirtualBytes, PrivateBytes, PoolNonpagedBytes) for memory leak

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, wmi

I have a windows 10 PC that sometimes runs low on memory per the Task Manager Performance screen. The PC is in a factory, runs 24/7 and is used by multiple, non technical users. ALSO - I DO NOT HAVE ADMIN ON THIS PC AND MOST OF THE TOOLS MENTIONED IN OTHER POSTS ARE BLOCKED.

I have a python logger that uses psutil and Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and its Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process class. PSUTIL isn't giving me complete data because of the no admin problem noted above but wmi is mostly available. I WOULD LIKE TO USE PYTHON  AND WMI.

What should I look at in the wmi class? (WorkingSet, VirtualBytes, PoolNonpagedBytes...)

Comment: Please don't use all caps - its considered as shouting.  I am not going to vote to reopen, until the post is cleaned up.